# Rails, pulling date into cookie expiry time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, model-view-controller, controller

I am currently building an online competition site. There is a resource called :weeks, which has a start_date and an end_date. This has_many :entries, and the entries can be upvoted and downvoted by creating and destroying votes. I am trying to set a cookie, so that a user can only vote once per week. But I can't get the cookie to set with the Weeks end_date set as the expiry.

If I use the following code in the EntriesController, the cookie sets:

```
def upvote
    @entry.votes.create
    cookies.permanent[:voted] = { value: "#{@week.title} voted" }

    redirect_to @week
end
```

However, when I try to pass in the weeks end_date, the cookie does not set and does not appear in the browser resources.

```
def upvote
    @entry.votes.create
    cookies[:voted] = { value: "#{@week.title} voted",
                        expires: @week.end_date.midnight }

    redirect_to @week
end
```

The Week is set in the entries controller using a `before_action` using:

`@week = Week.find(params[:week_id])`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you somehow put `puts @week.class` in your code to ensure it's returning a   `Time` object?

Comment: If I output `<%= @week.end_date.midnight %>` in the view, it shows on the page as `2015-03-05 00:00:00 UTC` - I'm fairly sure this should work, as the cookie sets using `7.days.from_now` which outputs as `2015-04-07 10:57:08 UTC` So the formats look the same, it just doesn't seem to be pulling it into the cookie correctly

Comment: Oh man, just from looking at this i've pasted in, I can see that the end date is being spat out as March 5, instead of April 5, so the cookie was setting an expiring immediately! Im so embarrassed right now!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it appears that `@week` is an instance variable. The `expires:` in cookies is expecting an object of the class `Time`. If, as it appears, you're @week.end_date is coming through as a String, you can do this:

```
 ...
  expires: Time.new(@week.end_date).midnight
```

Comment: Hmm, this is throwing a 'no implicit conversion of Date into Integer' error into the browser.